# Communicate back to the parent from facebook login popup

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, popupwindow, postmessage

I have a product page on a Magento server. There is a case where a user clicks on a button and a loader is shown on that page and if he is not logged in Facebook, a popup is opened using the Facebook PHP-SDK asking the user to log in. The PHP-SDK responsible for opening this login popup is hosted on another server, not the Magento server. I need a way to communicate back to the parent page once the user logs into Facebook so that I can hide the loader. As of now, what happens is that once the user logs in using the popup, the popup closes and there is no response back to the product page on the Magento server. Hence, there is no acknowledgement of the popup closing.

I have tried easyXDM and postmessage jquery plugin, but none of them could send back the response from the popup to the parent page. It works well for cases where the response is requested on the same page from where the event was fired even for cross domain. But, it is not working in case a popup is opened up.

I am not sure as to if this can even be achieved. But if there is way, I will be glad to get some help.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook SDK for PHP can work in conjunction with the Facebook SDK for Javascript to provide seamless session management across both the client and server-sides of an app.

In your existing code check whether following code is present or not. If not add and check result.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>',
      cookie: true,
      xfbml: true,
      oauth: true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
      // you can specify your location also.
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
      // you can specify your location also.
    });
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```